# No video out from ffmpeg h264_v4l2m2m encoder on rtmp or fifo file

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, video, codec

I am using ffmpeg to stream /dev/video0 to rtmp server.
I use -codec:v h264_v4l2m2m as encoder.

What ever I try I get no video out on the stream.
On my command line if I just replace -codec:v h264_v4l2m2m as -codec:v h264_omx I get video.

And if I capture the output as a video file, I get video.
But if I capture the output on a fifo file, then also I get no video.

This seems a well know bug in ffmpeg even on v6.0
But how come no one fixed this issue yet ?
Or I do some major mistake on my commands ?

As a workaround if I use pipe, then I get video with the same -codec:v h264_v4l2m2m. But pipe give some artifacts on video after few hours.

What's happening ?
How to fix this on the command line with some magic flags ?

Here is a sample commandline:

**NO VIDEO:**

`ffmpeg -re -input_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa  -ac 2  -thread_queue_size 2048 -i hw:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0 -strict -2 -codec:v h264_v4l2m2m -preset ultrafast -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr" -b:v 2500k -minrate 2500k -maxrate 2500k -bufsize:v 3750k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -codec:a aac -b:a 128k -tune zerolatency  -vf "format=yuv420p" -r 30 -g 30 -threads 0 -f flv rtmp://IP/live/KEY`

**YES VIDEO BUT ARTIFACTS AFTER FEW HOURS:**

`ffmpeg -re -input_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa  -ac 2  -thread_queue_size 2048 -i hw:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0 -strict -2 -codec:v h264_v4l2m2m -preset ultrafast -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr" -b:v 2500k -minrate 2500k -maxrate 2500k -bufsize:v 3750k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -codec:a aac -b:a 128k -tune zerolatency  -vf "format=yuv420p" -r 30 -g 30 -threads 0 -f flv - | ffmpeg -i - -c copy -f flv rtmp://IP/live/KEY`

**My System Info:**

Raspberry Pi 4 B+
OS: Raspberry Pi OS (Buster 32bit)
Memory: 4GB

**ffmpeg (v4.x, v5.x, v6.x):**

**configuration:** --extra-version=ffmpeg-2023 --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --prefix= --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --bindir=/home/pi/ffmpeg_build/ffmpeg-6.0/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-ldflags=-L/home/pi/ffmpeg_build/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm -latomic' --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=armhf --target-os=linux --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-nonfree --enable-gmp --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libsoxr --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libzimg --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-mmal --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-version3 --enable-pthreads --enable-openssl --enable-protocol=libsrt --enable-libsrt --enable-libpulse --enable-v4l2-m2m --enable-indev=alsa --enable-outdev=alsa --enable-swscale